# Working on CSS flexbox panel and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

Really stuck on the last bit of code in JavaScript. Basically, I have three panels in a Flexbox. Say if click the first panel, it will open wide and an img and text will appear, same for the second and third panel. However, if I have the first one open and then click the second panel the first still remains open, meaning the image and text looks tight, and even tighter when the third panel is open. How do I tell the browser that if I click the first panel to open and then the second one then close the first panel so there's room for the second panel?

```
    const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel')

     function toggleOpen() {
       this.classList.toggle('open')
     }

     function toggleActive(e) {
       if (e.propertyName.includes('flex')) {
       this.classList.toggle('open-active')
       }
     }

     panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen))
     panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('transitionend', toggleActive))

     panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
     panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('transitionend', toggleActive));

     // when I have one panel open and I click another panel the one that was open first closes
```

CSS

```
         *, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

img {
    width: 40%;
    height: 20%;
}

.panels {
  min-height:100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;    
}

.panel {
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  align-items:center;
  /* Safari transitionend event.propertyName === flex */
  /* Chrome + FF transitionend event.propertyName === flex-grow */
  transition:
    font-size 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.61,-0.19, 0.7,-0.11),
    flex 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.61,-0.19, 0.7,-0.11),
    background 0.2s;
  font-size: 20px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* Flex Children */

.panel > * {
  margin:0;
  transition:transform 0.5s;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.panel > *:first-child {transform: translateY(-100%);}
.panel.open-active > *:first-child {transform: translateY(0);}
.panel > *:last-child {transform: translateY(100%);}  
.panel.open-active > *:last-child {transform: translateY(-20%);}  

.panel p {
  color: black;
}
.panel p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.panel.open {
  flex: 5;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: I guess you are trying to make something like this.  https://codepen.io/vibhanshu/full/KbQvYX Please take a look ans see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function toggleOpen() {
    panels.forEach(function(panel){
    if(panel.classList.contains('open')
       panel.classList.remove('open');
    });
    this.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside toggle open function you can basically remove the `open` class from all the panels before adding `open` class to the clicked panel.

```
 function toggleOpen() {
      panels.forEach(panel => panel.classList.remove('open'));
      this.classList.toggle('open');
    }
```

You can take a look at the full code here. https://codepen.io/vibhanshu/pen/KbQvYX